# show my own admin_notices after a post has been published

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want show my own (2) admin_notices after a post is published.

How can i do this ?

P.s: I need this to show results of my external function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add Additional 'Published' Notices

You can use the following to **add** an additional admin notice after a post has been published:

```
add_action('admin_notices', function(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();     

    $editPostScreen = ($screen->parent_base == 'edit' && $screen->post_type == 'post') ? true : false;
    $justPublished = (isset($_GET['message']) && $_GET['message'] == '6') ? true : false;

    if ($editPostScreen && $justPublished) {

        $class = 'notice notice-info';
        $message = __( 'Just published a post custom text', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $message ) ); 

    }
});
```

*(`$justPublished` relies on `$_GET['message']`. This URL query variable is not visible in admin address bar as Wordpress actually [removes it from the URL with Javascript](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23367)! Took me a long while to figure that out, so although you can't see it, it actually exists!).*

---

### Edit The Default 'Published' Notice

You can use the following to **edit** the admin notice after a post has been published:

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', function($messages){
    $messages['post'][6] = __( 'Just published a post custom text', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    return $messages;
}, 10, 1 );
```